# Will it be still happening or will it still happen

Tags: continuous

I am waiting for a reissue of a book,but nothing seems to arrive so I decide to write an email

Shall I say "Will the reissue of this book still be happening  or will it still happen " I think first one is better because it is not a general statement

Comment: Why did you switch from putting adverbial ***still*** after the verb *(**be**)* in the title, but *before* the verb in the question text itself? Do you actually *mean* anything specific by including ***still*** anyway? Both your suggested phrasings are perfectly valid without it.

Answer (score 0):

- "Will it still happen", means something was planned in the future, and somebody is asking if it will still happen.
- "Will it be still happening", is less used, and a bit broad. But most likely it means that it's something starting to happen already, or in very near future, thus already starting to prepare for it.